# Detecting waypoints in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I just want to ask if this is possible in google map v3.I created a marker serve as my waypoints in directions and save those coordinates in my database. my concern for this is. Is it possible to detect one of my vehicle which I set for his waypoints and will know if he passes or not in that waypoints  that I created ?

just like this example created @geocodezip,with mulitple waypoints

[Multiple waypoints](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_multipleWayPts_CustomMrkrsB.html)

I want to detect the vehicle if he passes or not in that waypoints.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible (if you know where the vehicle is).

Comment: the vehicle will send actual coordinates to our server but how do I compare this to the coordinates of waypoints so that I will know it passes to the waypoints.?

Comment: @geocodezip, do I need another js plugin to detect if the vehilce is in the waypoints ?

Comment: @geocodezip, you said it's possible can you tell me some idea how ?In polygon I use the plugin,polygon.containsLatsLang.js,it can detect if the coorinates of vehicle is inside the polygon fences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over all legs and all steps of the legs.

For each step create a Polyline-object(must not be visible) and use `google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge()` to check if the given location(vehicle-position) is placed on the Polyline.

When it does, the vehicle has passed the waypoint specified by the start_location of the current leg(and probably the previous waypoints, when the vehicle was following the given route ).

Comment: ,Thank you for this idea,I will let you know if this will work.Thank you.